# What's the best way to POST / GET excel data

Tags: php, mysql, vba

Right now I have this vba script :

```
i = 11

While (Range("B" & i) <> "")
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
       URL = "https://example.com/submit/?no=" & Range("B" & i).Value & "&soal=" & Range("C" & i).Value & "&a=" & Range("E" & i).Value & "&b=" & Range("F" & i).Value & "&c=" & Range("G" & i).Value & "&d=" & Range("H" & i).Value & "&benar=" & Range("J" & i).Value & ""
       objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
       objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
       objHTTP.send ("")
    i = i + 1

Wend
```

It works fine and all. And does what I want. The Problem is, it took a long time (about 60 seconds) to post 60 questions. The 60 seconds isn't really a problem. I can wait for 60 seconds. The problem is within my hosting. They flag my IP me as SPAMMER or something. Because after I successfully post my the questions I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. It happens to me only. The site is fine if opened via Proxy.

So my question is, is there a way to POST 60 questions via excel vba to php without making my IP Blocked by the Hosting Provider.

the content of submit.php

```
<?php 
    include ('../db.php');
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `soal` (`id`, `no`, `soal`, `options`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `benar`) VALUES (NULL, "'.$_GET['no'].'", "'.$_GET['soal'].'", "4", "'.$_GET['a'].'", "'.$_GET['b'].'", "'.$_GET['c'].'", "'.$_GET['d'].'", "e", "'.$_GET['benar'].'");';
    $conn->query($sql);
```

Sample excel row
http://snag.gy/A4o9D.jpg

p.s. I know about mysql sanitation, security, injection and all, let's just focus on the matter at hand instead of talking about security.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note my vba is rusty (like, 10+ years), the string concatenation might be wrong, perhaps use `URL = URL & "...` rather than `URL &= "...`

but the basic idea is build one long query string, then make a single http request:

```
i = 11
URL = "https://example.com/submit/?"
While (Range("B" & i) <> "")

    URL &= "no[" & i & "]=" & Range("B" & i).Value & "&soal[" & i & "]=" & Range("C" & i).Value & "&a[" & i & "]=" & Range("E" & i).Value & "&b[" & i & "]=" & Range("F" & i).Value & "&c[" & i & "]=" & Range("G" & i).Value & "&d[" & i & "]=" & Range("H" & i).Value & "&benar[" & i & "]=" & Range("J" & i).Value

    i = i + 1

Wend

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
```

on the php side, you will get arrays, so build the query in a loop and insert all the values in one query as well:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `soal` (`id`, `no`, `soal`, `options`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `benar`) VALUES ';
$values = [];
foreach($_GET['no'] as $key => $ignore){
    $values[]= '(NULL, "'.$_GET['no'][$key].'", "'.$_GET['soal'][$key].'", "4", "'.$_GET['a'][$key].'", "'.$_GET['b'][$key].'", "'.$_GET['c'][$key].'", "'.$_GET['d'][$key].'", "e", "'.$_GET['benar'][$key].'")';
}
$sql .= implode(',', $values) . ';';
$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: I got the idea. I will try your theory. Quick questions, is there any limitation of how long the URL ? Because I tried to Google it I didn't find any definite answer .

Comment: yes, but its set on the web server. i notice you are creating  a POST request anyway, so instead of adding parameters to the url, send them in the post body. there is no such limit for post body size. i believe you would do that in vba by passing the post body string to `objHTTP.send("data string here")`